# Angular data-binding - set value of model manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running angular.js 1.4 and I have input with data-binding like this:

```
<input ng-model="name">
```

Is there a way how to set change value manually, without typing into input? Something like to call angular object, find the 'name' in the scope and then set it's value.

**EDIT!**

I need to do this from chrome extension's contentscript, that means I can't change the source code.

Comment: can you access the scope? `$scope["name"]` should give you access to that value and you can just set it. As mentioned in tekkavi's answer, you have to trigger a digest cycle to actually see the results, e.g. by triggering an `input event` on the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the scope of an element by calling `scope()` on the element itself. So, for simplicity's sake let's say that your textbox has an id of `myTextBox` and that `name` is a scope property. You could set the model value like this:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('myTextBox')).scope().name = 'someNewValue';
```

Comment: That would works, but I need to somehow run $apply. Do you know how exactly?

Comment: You have access to the scope with `scope()`, so just call `$apply()` on it.